# Unable to override text-align: justify with text-align: left in simple HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an odd issue with the `text-align: left` not working after the element has inherited a justify property.  I even tried using the !important keyword and it's still not working.  The odd thing is, if I use developer mode in Chrome, it **says** `text-align: left` is active, `text-align: justify` is inactive, but it is NOT rendering the left align.

Here is my code:  https://jsfiddle.net/h0vx9sLc/3/  (updated Fiddle with "fix")

```css
body { width: 100px; }
p:nth-child(1) {  }
p:nth-child(2) { text-align: justify; }
p>span { text-align: left !important; }
```

```html
<p>
    <span>Testing Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span>Testing Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</span>
</p>
```

Based on the CSS priority there really is no chance the `justify` property has a higher priority than `left`.  I tested this in Chrome, Firefox, and IE and all are doing the same thing.

Here is the screen shot of Chrome claiming the left property is active, but it isn't.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this is a VERY bizarre property of CSS.

I figured it out with the help of this question:  [text-align justify, cannot override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526624/text-align-justify-cannot-override)

Apparently an inline element IGNORES text-align CSS, but it can INHERIT them.  So my SPAN was inheriting the justify, but CSS rendering IGNORES the text-align CSS of an inline element.

To fix it, I add `display: inline-block;` to my span.  Really, really bizarre.
I'm not sure what to make of the Chrome developer issue.  I guess it should technically be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `class` to override the `justify` value or is there something I missed?

**Update:** `<span>`s are inline elements and `text-align` applies to **blocks** of text. So you have to apply `display:`**`block`** or `inline-`**`block`** on the `<span>`s or apply a `class`, an `id`, or an inline style to the `<p>`s.

```css
body {
  width: 100px;
}
p~p {
  text-align: justify;
}
p>span {
  text-align: left !important;
}
.left {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<p class="left">
  <span>Testing Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</span>
</p>
<p class="left">
  <span>Testing Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Your class just overrides the p element's text-align, you are not really doing anything with the spans.  If you set the spans to .left, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is throwing you off i think. The following from [teachbrij.com](http://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling) explain well.

~ Sign:

It is general sibling combinator and similar to Adjacent sibling combinator. the difference is that the second selector does NOT have to immediately follow the first one means It will select all elements that is preceded by the former selector.

Here is the [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp) rundown. Same info...

I have attached your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0vx9sLc/1/) in which I removed the the left justify. You will see that all of the multiple spans get thrown EXCEPT the first even though there is no

```
align: left
```

set.

Interesting question for sure. Hope this helps.

Comment: I know what the p~p does.  I want to show that without the justify, the first span behaves properly, but the second and onward span will suddenly be justified even though the span has a high priority `text-align: left` set.  I have also answered my question :)

Comment: Roger that you sure did! :) Very interesting stuff. As I was making Fiddle you answered. lol. Good one

Comment: I get it now. Very weird how inline block is required. Some things are just that way. How come in JS

{} + [] = 0

and

[] + {} = [object object]

Some things are just trip